How to reset a parameter value when disabled?
I use a lot of parameter annotations when developping components, in order to make them user-friendly, especially the Dialog(enable=...). However, when a parameter is disabled, it just prevents the user from modifying it afterwards, but it does not affect the value that may have been set beforehand. Here's an example:
model toto

  parameter Boolean isComplexModel=true;
  parameter Boolean isDynamicModel=false annotation (Dialog(enable=isComplexModel));

equation 

  // Mass and energy balance equations
  if isDynamicModel and isComplexModel then
    [...]
  else
    [...]
  end if;
  
  // Other part of the code
  if isComplexModel then
    [...]
  end if;
  
end toto;

In this example, the dynamic equations are used only if isDynamicModel=true, which should be available only if isComplexModel=true. However, I could set isDynamicModel=true and then isComplexModel=false in the instance. That's why I need to specify if isDynamicModel and isComplexModel.
Therefore, is there a way to modify (or at least reset) the value of a parameter when it is disabled?

From what I know, what you are doing is the best way of handling the enable annotation when the value has changed before it was disabled...

I'd rather prefer an enumeration parameter to avoid the invalid configuration of multiple parameters.

It should be possible to change the parameter in the text layer so:
model A
extends toto(isDynamicModel=true);
end A;
should work

I don't think that it is possible to change the parameter value when it is disabled.
You have three cases (simple, complex with dynamics, complex without dynamics). As tbeu mentioned, a better design would be to implement this as an enumeration.
If you want to use booleans, you could also implement an additional protected parameter
  parameter Boolean isComplexModel = true;
protected
  parameter Boolean hasDynamicBalance = isDynamicModel and isComplexModel;
[...]
  // Mass and energy balance equations
  if hasDynamicBalance then
    [...]
  else
    [...]
  end if;

If you implement the simple/complex sub-models replaceable, you might implement the dynamics parameter inside the complex sub-model. However, interfacing the sub-model is more complex.
  model ComplexModel
  extends BaseModel;
    parameter Boolean isDynamicModel=false
    [...]
    // Mass and energy balance equations
    if hasDynamicBalance then
      [...]
    else
      [...]
    end if;
  end ComplexModel;

  model SimpleModel
  extends BaseModel;
    [...]
  end SimpleModel;

  replaceable SimpleModel model constrainedby BaseModel;
...



I agree that an enumeration would be the proper way to code, but I don't think it would be really user-friendly in my case. Regarding the intermediate parameter, it doesn't simplify the code as I would have one more boolean to deal with. Thank you for your propositions, but I guess I'll leave it as it is.
